# Filter null objects from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to filter payloads like this on an ElasticSearch query:

```
{
  "bestPrices": {
    "cia1": {},
    "cia2": {}
  }
}
```

I must get only results like:

```
{
  "bestPrices": {
    "cia1": {
      "gol": {
        "price1": 799,
        "price2": null,
        "miles": 25000
      }
    },
    "cia2": {
      "gol": {
        "price1": null,
        "price2": null,
        "miles": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying `exists` query, but seems that it do not apply to this particular situation:

```
{
  "exists": {
    "field": "searchIntention.bestSalePrices.cia1"
  }
}
```

I'm using ElasticSearch 6.1

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticsearch Documentation for the [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) specifies that `null`, `[]`, and `[null]` qualify as non-existent values.  Therefore, I believe all other values, including an empty object (`{}`) would be considered non-null.  If the `go1` member of the `cia` object is always populated, you could try using `exists` on that field instead.

```
{
  "exists": {
   "field": "searchIntention.bestSalePrices.cia1.go1"
  }
}
```